# Changing/Editing tags with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

This is my first question here so please bear with me - I apologise if I have not posted correctly.

I have managed to pull a job description from an XML file created by our database however, the database software is very old and it converts certain
 characters.

My problem is as follows: Bullet points are converted to something like the following:

```
"   Production of Monthly Management Accounts and variance analysis<BR>
```

So a "(quote mark) is entered where the dot should be and a `<BR>` is entered to start a new line.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to convert the quote mark and the `<BR>` to `<li>` and `</li>` repspectively.
I've been looking at multiple options like,     `preg_match` and `substr_replace` however, none of them have given the desired results.

Obviously the text between the `<li>` and `</li>` would change depending on job etc.

To top it all off, once this is working I need to be able to add in `<ul>` and `</ul>` around the list items, but I assume I can look for the first instance of `<li>` and replace with `<ul><li>` and likewise the last instance of `</li>` and replace with `</li></ul>`.

I'm sorry for rambling on, I hope I've made myself clear.

**Edit:**
Thanks so much for all of the quick responses, I am going to give these a bash tomorrow. I've been stuck on this most of the day so think it's time to step away.

Just to give a bit of extra info if it helps...

The database software is about 12 years old and the support for it is quite limit. If we want something doing it tends to cost a lot of money. It has a few options to export the data however, the XML for whatever reason kept HTML formatting so I went with that route.

All of the jobs have been written in Word first and then pasted into the "job field" in the database, so there is a strong chance that code has been misinterpreted.

I did a test job and made sure I used bullet points in Word and copy - pasted it into the "job field", the quote marks appeared where the dots should be, so I assume the old software doesn't "understand" the bullet points.

I will try all your great responses and report back tomorrow!

Thanks!

**EDIT 2**

Hi, below I have pasted the actual output from source view.
I have attempted the preg_replace option below which works on a single line, but as you can see the output is annoyingly placing everything continuously with no line breaks.

```
An exciting opportunity has arisen to join an established company based in Luton for a high calibre Management Accountant. Reporting to the Finance Director, the Management Accountant will provide accurate and reliable management information and financial support to the business. <BR>Key Responsibilities:<BR>" Production of Monthly Management Accounts and variance analysis<BR>"    Preparation of Management Reports for Management Meetings.<BR>" Production of Monthly Forecasts and Annual Budgets using Excel.<BR>"    Decision support to the business<BR>"   Attending and presenting at meetings with business managers<BR>"    Assisting external auditors with their audit process at each year end<BR>"  Ad-hoc project work<BR>Experience:<BR>" Qualified accountant (ACA or CIMA) <BR>"    Strong communication skills - to communicate effectively with all levels of management<BR>" High level of personal motivation, focus and a commitment to quality<BR>"   Ability to adapt to the demands of a constantly changing business<BR>"  Ability to interact with people at all levels in a sensitive and effective way<BR>If you are interested in this role then please apply now.<BR>
```

Comment: Your first question here is a good example that many others should look at before posting anything... Nevertheless - what did you try so far? Especially your `preg_match` and `substr_replace` solutions look interesting. Maybe an answerer could continue from what you tried.

Comment: Is a  1 item list a possibility? (so just in `<li />` in an `<ul />`?

Comment: Upvoted for clear, well formed question :-)

Comment: I've seen many questions on how to preg_replace weird characters and they're normally the result of disregarding the character sets used by the database and the script. Are you sure bullets are *converted* rather than *misinterpreted*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `"` begins the line (quote followed by 3 spaces, markdown is removing the spaces)
- `<BR>` is at the very end of the line
- There will be no other variation, nor split lines

RegEx:

```
/^"   (.*)<BR>$/
```

PHP:

```
$replacedData = preg_replace( '/^"   (.*)<BR>$/', '<li>\1</li>', $data );
```

As you've said that the content is all lumped together, you could try this regex:

```
/"   (.*?)<BR>/
```

Although you should be warned that it may pick up the wrong quote if the lines happen to contain "quoted" text.

Alternatively, if you know that the lines end as `<BR>"` (3 spaces being removed due to markdown), you could use 3 replaces to get the desired effect:

```
$repData = preg_replace(
             array( '/<BR>"   /', '<BR>', '"   ' ),
             array( '</li><li>', '</li></ul>', '<ul><li>' ),
             $data );
```

Again, this may pick up the wrong elements especially if `<BR>` exists elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this suggestion, it works brilliantly on a single line. I should have mentioned (sorry) that the output is putting everything continuously on a single line so this preg_replace doesn't seem to work, is there a way of saying "at each "(quote) run preg_replace"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First comment would be to fix the broken database.

Aside from that, why is there formatting in an XML file, or in a database for that matter? If this is an XML file, just strip everything but the actual job description text out of the element, and have your PHP script output it nicely. Given the example above, trim the 
 from the trailing end, then run it through trim('" ') to clean up any enclosing quotes and whitespace.

Or is this one of those cases where you're getting XML from a database, and whoever wrote that part clearly didn't understand what XML is for?

**Edit:**
Ahhh. It just hit me. Maybe you mean the job description is a plain text blob, with what *should* be sub-items actually all jammed in there, formatted as you demonstrated. If that's the case, you're going to have a *really* hard time getting this exact, because the odds are (when working with unstructured data) there are some variances in formatting. I think your best bet would be a regex to pull out all the text between " and the BR tags, build an array of that, and manually check some samples. Oh, and fix the database.

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge of XML is very limited, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's been coded wrongly and misused.

I like the idea of pulling out the text between the " and BR tags, I will look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've extracted to a variable; for sake of ease of demonstration i'll just set one:

```
$myVar = '"   Production of Monthly Management Accounts and variance analysis<BR>';
```

As the other answer says, [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is your friend, and so is either [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) depending specifically what you want to do and what else you might have in your database.

Try this (assuming that you have stored the content in $myVar, as I have in my example).

```
$cleanedVar = strip_tags(trim($myVar,'" '));
```

Or this:

```
$cleanedVar = str_replace("<BR>","",trim($myVar,'" '));
```

Both of these lines would give you a result in $cleanedVar as

**Production of Monthly Management Accounts and variance analysis**

Comment: One thing I've noticed with the Trim idea, is (and I should have mentioned this in my original post, sorry) there is a bit of blurb above the bullet points giving a brief overview of the job.

So if I Trim all of the `<BR>` that would remove them from the whole description, is there a way of removing the next `<BR>` found after a `<li>` ?

Comment: I think to do that you will definately need to explore the regular expression functions.  You could do worse than editing your question and posting the full markup you get from the database (maybe even more than one example) and specify which bits you want to lose, and which bits you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks, I will post the output to my original post tomorrow!